# Kubernetes memory requests and limits fixed-point vs power-of-two

Tags: kubernetes, memory

There are two examples on kubernetes.io about how to specify memory request and limits and they are very confusing.

(I removed `cpu` and the unnecessary quote characters from the following examples.)

**Example 1:**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: 64Mi
  limits:
    memory: 128Mi
```

**Example 2:**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 200Mi
  requests:
    memory: 100Mi
```

Both examples are valid expressions but when using power-of-two suffix shouldn't you aim for always using `8`, `16`, `32`, `64`, `128`, `256`, `512`, `1028` and so on?

I think that the person from example nr 2 didn't really know what she/he was doing and she/he should have used fixed-point suffix, `200M` and `100M`, instead?

If I were to specify `268435456` bytes using power-of-two suffix how would I express that in my yaml config; `250Mi` or `256Mi`?

Comment: `100Mi` is 104,857,600 bytes; there's nothing syntactically or semantically wrong with it as a limit, and it's about 20% less memory than `128Mi`.

Answer (score 2):

> I think that the person from example nr 2 didn't really know what she/he was doing and she/he should have used fixed-point suffix, 200M and 100M, instead?

No. `Mi` and `M` are units representing certain number of bytes. `Mi` is (2<sup>10)<sup>2</sup></sup> bytes  (1048576 bytes) and `M` is (10<sup>3)<sup>2</sup></sup> bytes (1000000 bytes). The number you place before these units doesn't matter except for as a multiplication factor. There is no requirement that the prefix number should be a multiple of two or anything.

200M = 200 x (10<sup>3)<sup>2</sup></sup> bytes = 200000000 bytes

200Mi = 200 x (2<sup>10)<sup>2</sup></sup> bytes = 209715200 bytes

---

> If I were to specify 268435456 bytes using power-of-two suffix how would I express that in my yaml config; 250Mi or 256Mi?

268435456 bytes = 268435456/1048576 Mi = 256Mi

268435456 bytes = 268435456/1000000 M = 268.435456M

---

From [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-memory)

> Limits and requests for memory are measured in bytes. You can express memory as a plain integer or as a fixed-point number using one of these suffixes: E, P, T, G, M, K. You can also use the power-of-two equivalents: Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki. For example, the following represent roughly the same value:
>
> 128974848, 129e6, 129M, 123Mi

Comment: I see your point. But this topic is confusing and I noticed and I kinda knew it would turn out this ways because I hardly know how to present the question. I know that ultimately bytes will be used behind the scenes and you can specify whatever you want but what I think I'm trying to get at here is what's the best practice for power of two units.

Comment: I mean say you want to specify "250 megabytes" or however you would say when speaking to a person. We all understand what you're saying but how do you specify it so that it makes sense to everyone reading your configuration. Is there any consensus is maybe what I'm trying to say? I'm still not sure I've made my thoughts clear.

Comment: See for instance this page and how they're specifying it in a consistent manner https://www.astronomer.io/docs/enterprise/v0.16/manage-astronomer/configure-platform-resources They're not using the values 250 or 500 even though that's what they mean.

Comment: I feel like you are overthinking this. Whether you use the [binary prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) or decimal prefix, it's just a way to represent a quantity in slightly different way. Previously kilo from the decimal system was used when one meant 1024 bytes and everyone involved understood. In SI system, kilo means 1000 though. The binary prefixes(kibi, mebi) is  a way to be precise in terms of terminology. You can choose whichever you are comfortable with and stick with it. If you mean 1024 bytes, use 1Ki. If you mean 1000 bytes, use K.